# What is the difference between P(A|B,C) and P(A|B∩C)

Tags: conditional-probability, notation

Is it the same? If yes, which one is the more common/correct notation?

Answer (score 4):

$P(A \,\text{and}\, B)$, $P(A \cap B)$, $P(A,B)$ all mean [joint probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution). The conditional notation you mention means conditioning on two variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Which one would you consider more common? (I'm currently writing a documentation for a software)

Comment: It depends on whether $A$ represents a random variable (first) or an event (second).

Comment: So, if I say: "The probability of an event A, given the information B is available and the mechanism C exists",it should be noted as "A|B∩C"?

Comment: @309963d8521805330a44bdcb3d87f3 It’s “probability of A given B and C”, e.g. “probability that it will rain given that it is cloudy *and* windy now”.